# Reduction from deciders of the universal to deciders of the empty language

Tags: computability, reductions

$ALL_{TM} = \{\langle M\rangle | \; M$ is $TM$ and  $L(M)=\Sigma^*\}$
$E_{TM} = \{\langle M\rangle | \; M$ is $TM$ and  $L(M)=\emptyset\}$

I can't find reduction of $ALL_{TM}$ to $E_{TM}$. But I can't proof that it does not exist. 
Is there is such a reduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point to note is if you can reduce $L_1$ to $L_2$ then the same reduction/mapping can be used to see that $\overline{L_1}$ is reducible to $\overline{L_2}$.  The following is the proof, avoid if you just needed the hint. 
Now we know $E_{TM}$ is not Turing recognizable but $\overline{E_{TM}}$ is. Secondly we know $\overline{ALL_{TM}}$ is not Turing recognizable  . So say if $ALL_{TM}$ is reducible to $E_{TM}$, then it would mean  $\overline{ALL_{TM}}$ is reducible to $\overline{E_{TM}}$, and as $\overline{E_{TM}}$ is Turing recognizable $\overline{ALL_{TM}}$ would become Turing recognizable which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes other moderators told me that. I was ready to remove my answer but it was decided that in future I should not post answers to questions directly asking for solutions. Now I take care of it.

Comment: Okay, never mind then. :) (Please flag this for removel after reading. Thanks!)